# HDD space in Ubuntu Apache server is running out

Tags: mysql, apache, server, google-cloud-platform

I've created a **10 GB HDD and 3.75 GB RAM instance in Google Cloud** and hosted a quite heavy DB transaction application's backend/API there. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm using Apache web server with PHP and MySQL for the backend. The problem here is that the HDD space has almost run out of memory very quickly.

Using Linux (Ubuntu) commands, I've found that my source code (/var/www/html) size is about 200 MB and the MySQL DB folder (/var/lib/mysql) size is 3.7 GB (around 20,000,000 records in my project DB). I'm confused how rest of my HDD space is occupied (except OS files). As of today, I only have 35 MB left. Once for testing purpose, I copied the source code to another folder. Even then I had the same problem. When I realized that my HDD space is running out, I deleted that folder and freed around 200 MB. But later (around 10 minutes) that freed space has also gone!!!

I figured that some log file like Apache error log, access log, MySQL error log or CakePHP debug log may occupy that space but I've disabled and truncated those files long ago and checked if these file are creating again but it doesn't. So how????????

I'm seriously worried about this project to continue with this instance. I thought about adding additional HDD to remedy this situation but I need to be sure how my HDD space is being occupied first. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `ncdu` tool might be helpful here. It gives you an overview of where your disk space went. If the disk is not *entirely* full, you should be able to install it with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by searching all the largest files in your system.

On the / directory type:

```
sudo find . -type f -size +5000k -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Once you find the files you can start to troubleshoot.
If you get many file you can increase +5000k to aim for the larger files.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it to sort out the problem.